# How to access heroku postgres Database with ruby on rails in shopify app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, heroku-postgres, shopify-app

Hello I am working on a shopify embedded app with ruby on rails and I must save some config parameters given by the user or me.
I couldn't find any solution other than using heroku postgres database.

I looked everywhere for a code to insert or select data from the heroku database but I was unsuccessful in the Doc they literally gave one line of code in Ruby section.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-ruby

in the Gemfile add :

```
gem 'pg'
```

I have no idea how to execute any Query on the database with ruby in my controller.

**EDIT :
I did all the configuration for the pg gem all I need to know is some example of code on how to use it**

Use case example:

1. The app home have Input and Save button.
2. User 1 Enter data in input and Click save.
3. User 1 close the app.
4. User 1 returns to the app.
5. User 1 finds the data he wrote in the input.

Please help.

Comment: Did you provision a Heroku Postgres addon? Did you do the set  up as described in the article you linked? Did you generate a `Config` model (or whatever you want to call it)? Did you migrate your database on Heroku? Did you generate a `Config` scaffold? If not, in which controller are you trying to save your 'config parameters'?

Comment: Unfortunately, we're only here to solve specific programming problems. This is a configuration issue. Also, this is a general framework issue. I think you need to learn how to connect to a database in Ruby on Rails. Then, make your best effort to setup the configuration file in Heroku's production instance to connect to your remote instance. Then, if you are encountering errors, come back and let us know that specific error, the code that you tried, and the results you expected.

Comment: I did all of that It's not a configuration problem I want to know the syntax of ruby I am supposed to use in order to execute queries. The DOC provided JAVA code and there is plenty of code in other languages but not in Ruby.

Comment: Still don't understand why would someone down vote a direct and clear question with no duplicate and literally 0 Ruby code provided by the documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It with the help of reddit community.

All I had to do is adding this in my controller:

```
@mydb = PG.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
```

Query Example

```
@mydb.exec('insert into table values (\'test2\',\'test2\',\'2\');')
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be more usual to save configuration info as heroku config vars, rather than in Postgres.

`heroku config` will list the current vars and `heroku config:set VAR_NAME=var_value` will set vars. This is not Ruby code - it is a part of heroku setup.

If you truly want to write Ruby on Rails code to modify the database, you need to learn [ActiveRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-article-model)

Comment: I don't think that a heroku config will help me as I said the config must be given when the app is already installed for example I give the user an Input whith a save button and when he click save and leave the app and return he will still find the input with the same value. Is this possible with heroku config ? Thanks for the Hint on ActiveRecord I will look at it Asap